# UIView is equal to 0x0

Tags: cocoa-touch, iboutlet

I have a UIView in my application. I also have an object with an IBOutlet that is connected to my view. I have checked and rechecked, and I am positive they are connected. But for some reason, every time I try to draw the view in my UIWindow, it never draws. So, I looked in the debugger. It showed that my view was equal to 0x0, even though it's connected properly in IB. In addition, my UIWindow is equal to 0x0 as well, and it too is connected. What could I be doing wrong? Why are my IBOutlets all equal to 0x0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the right nib file?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. I only have one nib file with my window and view. I thought the nib was already loaded when the app started. Do I need to load the nib again?

Comment: Is it in the MainMenu.xib then?

Comment: Yes. Everything is currently in MainMenu.xib.

Comment: And you're connecting the view to your app delegate?

Comment: The view wasn't connected to the app delegate. It was connected to another object. Should all my interface objects be connected to the app delegate?

Comment: It depends on where you want to use it. Try it with the app delegate and if it works the problem is with your object. Make sure the iboutlet property is a retained property.

Comment: It was originally in the app delegate, but I was trying to separate some of my code into another file. I take it that's a bad idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had my IBOutlets connected to something other than the app delegate. Reconnecting them to the app delegate fixed the problem.

Thanks @Fabian for helping!